# Laravel form submission with url parameters

Tags: php, laravel, forms, http

When the user accesses a certain brand page, I pull the information associated with that brand. Then the user has the chance to submit an application for this brand.

When the user submits the form, I want the form to post to `/apply/brand/{brand_id}` because I want to store this application in my application table with the `brand_id` as one of the fields (the other fields in this table comes from the fields in my form, but the `brand_id` will be an URL parameter)

The problem is that when I submit the form, the form posts to **/apply/brand/undefined** and the submission does not work correctly. I do not reach the `ApplicationController@apply_store` method.

**EDIT:**
To debug my problem, I printed out the {{$brand -> id }} right before the  element and it printed out fine. However, when the form submits, it goes to /apply/brand/undefined instead of /apply/brand/{{$brand -> id }}. The $brand variable somehow becomes undefined inside of my form.

**EDIT:**
I hardcoded the from to submit to /apply/brand/43. When I press submit, the url shows up as /apply/brand/43 at first but then quickly changes to /apply/brand/undefined before redirecting me to my default page.

**Controller Method for Accessing a Brand Page**

```
public function brandProfile(){
        $brand = Brand::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->first();
        $industry = Industry::where('status', 1)->get();
        return view('new-design.pages.profile_brand')
                            ->withData($brand)
                            ->withIndustry($industry);
}
```

**Brand Application Form**

```
<form id="application_form" method="post" action="/apply/brand/{{ $data -> id }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  {{ csrf_field() }}
  <ul>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <li>
            <label>First Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name"/>
        </li>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <li>
            <label>Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name"/>
        </li>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <li>
            <label>Email</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email"/>
        </li>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <li>
            <label>Instagram Handle</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="instagram" placeholder="Instagram Handle"/>
        </li>
      </div>
        <li>
            <label>Cover Letter</label>
            <p>Please write your message in the space below, or attach a file (-list of file types accepted-)</p>
            <textarea cols="30" rows="50" name="message" class="textarea"></textarea>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="upload-cover-letter">
              <i class="fa fa-paperclip" style="cursor:pointer;font-size:20px;"></i>
              <input type="file" name="file" id="myFileDocument" class="inputfile inputfile-1"/>
              <label for="myFileDocument" id="myFileDoc"><span>Choose File</span></label>
              <span style="font-size: 12px">No File Chosen</span>
              <span class='hidden_text' style="font-size: 12px">Upload File (Max 2MB)</span>
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" id="myFileName" name="file_name" />
        </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="btn-center">
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-gradient waves-effect" id="create_campaign">Apply Now</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

**Route in web.php**

```
Route::post('/apply/brand/{brand_id}', 'ApplicationController@apply_store');
```

**Store application in database**

```
public function apply_store(Request $request)
    {
        $application = new Application([
            'influencer_id' => Auth::id(),
            'brand_id' => $request->get('brand_id'),
            'message' => $request->get('message'),
            'status' => 'applied'
        ]);
        $application->save();

        // TODO: add helper message to confirm application did return
        return redirect('/apply');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your controoler metohd apply_store, you need to put the variable that will receive the variable sended by url parameter.

public function apply_store(Request $request, $brand_id){}

Answer (score 0):

I typically work with `compact` or `with` to send the param to the blade view.  So:

```
return view('new-design.pages.profile_brand', compact('brand'));
```

or without compact:

```
return view('new-design.pages.profile_brand')->with('brand', $brand)
```

I haven't seen the `withVar` that you are attempting above (doesn't mean it doesn't exist though).  Try with compact and dump $`brand` on the view to make sure its coming through with data (not undefined).  If that dumps successfully, but still fails, you may want to try adding the variable outside the quotes or totally within the blade `{{}}` in the form like:

```
<form id="application_form" method="post" action={{ "/apply/brand/".$brand-> id }} enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Not sure about how the action is getting though like you have in your code above, though - you might wish to use the `url()` method:

```
<form id="application_form" method="post" action={{ url("/apply/brand/".$brand-> id) }} enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Answer (score 0):

change your method like this

```
public function apply_store(Request $request,$brand_id)
    {
        $application = new Application([
            'influencer_id' => Auth::id(),
            'brand_id' => $rbrand_id,
            'message' => $request->get('message'),
            'status' => 'applied'
        ]);
        $application->save();

        // Ngentod lah kalian semua, anjeng
        return redirect('/apply');
    }
```